# Can't pass argument from parent to child widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't seem to pass a simple int  for some reason. This is what I'm doing:

```
print("here we have ${widget.which}"); //prints here we have 1
    return Scaffold(
    body:ScrollablePositionedListPage(neducem:widget.which)


class ScrollablePositionedListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  late int neducem;
  ScrollablePositionedListPage({required int neducem});

  @override
  ScrollablePositionedListPageState createState() {
    print("and here we have $neducem"); //this line throws exception : Field 'neducem' has not been initialized
    return ScrollablePositionedListPageState();}
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor is not set corectly.

```
ScrollablePositionedListPage({required int neducem});
```

To fix it:

```
ScrollablePositionedListPage({required this.neducem}); # add this
```

or

```
ScrollablePositionedListPage({required int neducem}): this.neducem=neducem; # add this
```

More about constructors https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors

Comment: that's what I'm passing. The int called neducem. Is there something wrong with the constructor line, or why did you include it in your answer?

Comment: @Cavitedev it does not ;)

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. I think it is a very common practice to make it final though.

Comment: @Cavitedev you can see it often, but for e.g. https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors is not using final

Comment: Yeah, there are several approaches to this. But if he is not going to modify it I personally suggest making it final instead of late. At least that's what I would be doing here.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using constructors properly. That data you are passing isn't being saved anywhere. Most of the times you can solve this with final fields and on the constructor use `this.which`. That way when you fill this, that data will be filled correctly.

```dart
print("here we have ${widget.which}"); //prints here we have 1
    return Scaffold(
    body:ScrollablePositionedListPage(neducem:widget.which)


class ScrollablePositionedListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int neducem;
  ScrollablePositionedListPage({required this.neducem});

  @override
  ScrollablePositionedListPageState createState() {
    print("and here we have $neducem"); //It should work
    return ScrollablePositionedListPageState();}
```

From your approach, if you ever need to change neducem which is not usually the case you may try something like this manual approach of assignining variables:

```dart
print("here we have ${widget.which}"); //Now should work
    return Scaffold(
    body:ScrollablePositionedListPage(neducem:widget.which)


class ScrollablePositionedListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  late int neducem;
  ScrollablePositionedListPage({required int neducem}) : this.neducem = neducem;

  @override
  ScrollablePositionedListPageState createState() {
    print("and here we have $neducem"); //Now should work
    return ScrollablePositionedListPageState();}
```

Tell me if it works.